# Attempting to Modify Object Outside of Write Transaction

Tags: ios, uialertview, realm

So I have no idea why I am getting this error. The error message is as follows:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on a RLMRealm instance first.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2f7b0f83 0x39f61ccf 0xc46ef 0xc3c23 0xc0c9d 0xb3e73 0x3a449833 0x3a449ded 0x3a44a297 0x3a45c88d 0x3a45cb21 0x3a58bbd3 0x3a58ba98)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

And is thrown while executing this code.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    UITextField * alertTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    if (![self.chatSession.theirAlias isEqualToString:alertTextField.text]) {
        self.sender = alertTextField.text;
        dispatch_queue_t queue = ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).queueForWrites;
        dispatch_async(queue, ^{
            [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] beginWriteTransaction];
            self.chatSession.myAlias = alertTextField.text; // This is the line where the error is thrown
            [[RLMRealm defaultRealm] commitWriteTransaction];
        });
    } else {
        [self promptForAliasAfterRejection];
    }
}
```

It's pretty clear that I am writing inside of a write transaction. Is this a bug with Realm? Or am I missing something...?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `beginWriteTransaction` and `commitWriteTransaction` have to be called on the same realm the object you're modifying is in. Each time you call `[RLMRealm defaultRealm]`, you're getting a new realm. This is not going to be the same realm that's in `self.chatSession`. To fix this, first confirm that `self.chatSession`'s realm is on the same queue as your `queueForWrites` (I'm assuming `self.chatSession` is a `RLMObject`, of course). Then, just do the following inside the block instead:

```
[self.chatSession.realm beginWriteTransaction];
self.chatSession.myAlias = alertTextField.text;
[self.chatSession.realm commitWriteTransaction];
```