# Realm crashes on update the record

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I faced with the issue, where on update the exist record it crashes my app. This is my code:

```
if self.statisticsArray.count == 0 {
    try! self.realm.write({
        self.statistics.summary = 500
        self.realm.add(self.statistics)

        self.realm.add(record)
    })
} else {
    if day == self.statisticsArray.last?.date {
        try! self.realm.write({
             self.realm.objects(Statistics).last?.summary += 500
             self.realm.add(record)
        })
} else {
   try! self.realm.write({
        self.statistics.summary = (self.statisticsArray.last?.summary)! + 500
        self.realm.add(self.statistics)

        self.realm.add(record)
   })
}
```

I've putted all update processes into the `write` blocks, so why it crashes my app? Can anyone describe me, what is going wrong here and how can I fix it?

**Error**:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'
```

**UPDATE**

```
do {
    try self.realm.write({
        self.statistics.mlSummary = 250
        self.realm.add(self.statistics)

        self.realm.add(record)
   })
} catch let error {
    print("E \(error)")
}
```

Comment: @EricD. oh sorry, I forgot to add the error message. I've added it to my question, please read it

Comment: No problem. My suggestion about using Do-Try-Catch instead of `try!` is still valid, though. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051577/attempting-to-modify-object-outside-of-write-transaction

Comment: @Woodstock if I use `write` then I do not need `begin end transaction`

Comment: @EricD. look at please my update part. I did how you said and I still get the same error. Or I did something wrong?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear: I'm suggesting Do-Try-Catch not because it will fix your issue but because it's a better way to handle errors for throwing functions. Using `try!` can lead to more problems than you already have. That's all I was saying. :)

Comment: @EricD. Thanks :) Could you help me with this issue?)

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea. Be assured that otherwise I would have posted an answer already. ;) I hope you'll get help, best of luck to you!

Comment: anyone, who can help me?

Comment: I'd suggest [adding an exception breakpoint in Xcode](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/01/23/xcode-tips-1-break-on-exceptions). When the breakpoint triggers, look up the call stack until you see your app's code. That should point you at the line of code that is modifying a Realm object outside of a write transaction.